# boost-python example doesn't link under clang-darwin toolset

Tags: c++, clang, boost-python

I've installed boost-python on other macs in the past without issues, but for some reason I'm running into a problem on my new MacBook.  When I try to run the "quickstart" boost-python examples, bjam hangs while linking the second one.  Here's my build log, which shows that the first example builds and passes, but the second one never finishes linking (bjam hangs on the last line of the log).  Any guesses as to what could be causing this?

(By the way, I'm using python 2.7, boost 1.49, osx 10.7, and clang 3.1)

```
>>> cd boost_1_49_0/libs/python/example/quickstart/
>>> ../../../../bjam -a --verbose-test test
...patience...
...patience...
...found 1692 targets...
...updating 40 targets...
darwin.compile.c++ bin/darwin-4.2.1/debug/embedding.o
darwin.compile.c++ ../../../../bin.v2/libs/python/build/darwin-4.2.1/debug/numeric.o
darwin.compile.c++ ../../../../bin.v2/libs/python/build/darwin-4.2.1/debug/list.o
darwin.compile.c++ ../../../../bin.v2/libs/python/build/darwin-4.2.1/debug/long.o
darwin.compile.c++ ../../../../bin.v2/libs/python/build/darwin-4.2.1/debug/dict.o
darwin.compile.c++ ../../../../bin.v2/libs/python/build/darwin-4.2.1/debug/tuple.o
darwin.compile.c++ ../../../../bin.v2/libs/python/build/darwin-4.2.1/debug/str.o
darwin.compile.c++ ../../../../bin.v2/libs/python/build/darwin-4.2.1/debug/slice.o
darwin.compile.c++ ../../../../bin.v2/libs/python/build/darwin-4.2.1/debug/converter/from_python.o
darwin.compile.c++ ../../../../bin.v2/libs/python/build/darwin-4.2.1/debug/converter/registry.o
darwin.compile.c++ ../../../../bin.v2/libs/python/build/darwin-4.2.1/debug/converter/type_id.o
darwin.compile.c++ ../../../../bin.v2/libs/python/build/darwin-4.2.1/debug/object/enum.o
darwin.compile.c++ ../../../../bin.v2/libs/python/build/darwin-4.2.1/debug/object/class.o
darwin.compile.c++ ../../../../bin.v2/libs/python/build/darwin-4.2.1/debug/object/function.o
../../../../libs/python/src/object/function.cpp: In member function ‘PyObject* boost::python::objects::function::call(PyObject*, PyObject*) const’:
../../../../libs/python/src/object/function.cpp:169: warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type
darwin.compile.c++ ../../../../bin.v2/libs/python/build/darwin-4.2.1/debug/object/inheritance.o
darwin.compile.c++ ../../../../bin.v2/libs/python/build/darwin-4.2.1/debug/object/life_support.o
darwin.compile.c++ ../../../../bin.v2/libs/python/build/darwin-4.2.1/debug/object/pickle_support.o
darwin.compile.c++ ../../../../bin.v2/libs/python/build/darwin-4.2.1/debug/errors.o
darwin.compile.c++ ../../../../bin.v2/libs/python/build/darwin-4.2.1/debug/module.o
darwin.compile.c++ ../../../../bin.v2/libs/python/build/darwin-4.2.1/debug/converter/builtin_converters.o
darwin.compile.c++ ../../../../bin.v2/libs/python/build/darwin-4.2.1/debug/converter/arg_to_python_base.o
darwin.compile.c++ ../../../../bin.v2/libs/python/build/darwin-4.2.1/debug/object/iterator.o
darwin.compile.c++ ../../../../bin.v2/libs/python/build/darwin-4.2.1/debug/object/stl_iterator.o
darwin.compile.c++ ../../../../bin.v2/libs/python/build/darwin-4.2.1/debug/object_protocol.o
darwin.compile.c++ ../../../../bin.v2/libs/python/build/darwin-4.2.1/debug/object_operators.o
darwin.compile.c++ ../../../../bin.v2/libs/python/build/darwin-4.2.1/debug/wrapper.o
darwin.compile.c++ ../../../../bin.v2/libs/python/build/darwin-4.2.1/debug/import.o
darwin.compile.c++ ../../../../bin.v2/libs/python/build/darwin-4.2.1/debug/exec.o
darwin.compile.c++ ../../../../bin.v2/libs/python/build/darwin-4.2.1/debug/object/function_doc_signature.o
darwin.link.dll ../../../../bin.v2/libs/python/build/darwin-4.2.1/debug/libboost_python.dylib
darwin.link bin/darwin-4.2.1/debug/embedding
testing.capture-output bin/test_embed.test/darwin-4.2.1/debug/test_embed.run
====== BEGIN OUTPUT ======
registering extension module embedded_hello...
defining Python class derived from Base...
testing derived class from C++...
success!
running file script.py...
Hello World !
success!
intentionally causing a python exception...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'unknown' is not defined
No errors detected.

EXIT STATUS: 0
====== END OUTPUT ======
**passed** bin/test_embed.test/darwin-4.2.1/debug/test_embed.test
common.mkdir bin/test_ext.test
common.mkdir bin/test_ext.test/darwin-4.2.1
common.mkdir bin/test_ext.test/darwin-4.2.1/debug
darwin.compile.c++ bin/darwin-4.2.1/debug/extending.o
darwin.link.dll bin/darwin-4.2.1/debug/extending.so
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds a lot like [this](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/2185) bug. I wasn't able to find a fix myself, but I have been using Boost.Python regardless for the last few weeks without it affecting me in my own code.

Note that if your Python test file (perhaps invoked after a build) hangs for any reason (such as at a pdb breakpoint), then you'll see similar behaviour.

Comment: I forgot I had posted this question.  Thanks for the response.  [This post](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.build/24829) from the boost-build mailing list confirms that you identified the correct issue (but does not resolve anything).  The rest of that thread devolves into an unrelated issue.